# Output is not formatting correctly

Tags: python, function, floating-point

Writing a function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. I must find the Fahrenheit equivalent to each Celsius value and print both side by side in a two column chart. The numbers MUST BE FORMATTED TO ONE(1) OR TWO(2) DECIMAL PLACES. Everything works except the format to two decimal places.

```
    def temp():
    g = range(0, 100)
    for temp in g:
        F = (9 / 5) * (temp) + (32)
        print("{:.2f}". format(F))    
        print(f'{float(temp)} {float(F):>25}')
    return F
print(temp())
```

.The last few lines(all the other lines are functioning except the last)

```
98.0        208.40                     
210.20      208.4
99.0        210.20000000000002
210.20000000000002
```

how do I get the last number from both columns to have only 1 or 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
F = round((9 / 5) * (temp) + (32), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `print(f'{float(temp)} {float(F):>25.2f}')` to replace the 2nd print statement should accomplish this.
And to do the same thing on the last line on the right you could replace the final print with `print(f'{temp():>25.2f}')`.

the `.2f` rounds to 2 decimal places like you have in the first print.

See [the python PEP docs for more info on string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Use round

Change last line to
`return round(F,2)`